# Passing string containing an Html.ActionLink to a view from a controller

Tags: c#, html, string, controller

In my controller I have a string containing C#, something like

```
 viewModel.Message = 'blah blah <%=Html.ActionLink("","","")%> blah';
```

and in the corresponding view I have tried

- `Model.Message`
- `@Html.Raw(Model.Message)`

to get it to display correctly, with no luck - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create an instance of `HtmlHelper` in your controller for that, and have your message set to

```
viewModel.Message = "blah blah" + htmlHelper.ActionLink("","","") + " blah";
```

But do you really want your controller to be concerned with things like rendering HTML links? If you cannot delegate the task to the View entirely, how about just setting a Url property? You are able to access `Url.Action("","")` from your controller.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I would not do this - just one small bit of the website we're maintaining does it, so I'm leaving it like that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just call `ActionLink` in the controller  and add the result top your string -

```
viewModel.Message = "blah blah " + Html.ActionLink("","","") + " blah";
```